# how to package a docker image in a single file

Tags: docker

I have a 5GB docker image named "ubuntu-dev-update-15", which I developed on my local Ubuntu 14 dev machine.
In that image I have everything I need to do my development work.
Now I need to be able to send this image to a different linux host.
What is the procedure for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get an account on docker hub.

```
https://hub.docker.com/account/signup/
```

once signed up (only do that once), you log in from the host that has the image you want to push:

```
docker login
    (login with your username, password, and email address)
```

then you push your image up there.  you probably will need to tag it first. say you created a new account called mynewacc, first, you tag your image:

```
docker tag ubuntu-dev-update-15 mynewacc/ubuntu-dev-update-15
```

then push the image up to your docker hub:

```
docker push mynewacc/ubuntu-dev-update-15
```

now anybody else with docker can pull your image down:

```
docker pull mynewacc/ubuntu-dev-update-15
```

then to run the image:

```
docker run -it mynewacc/ubuntu-dev-update-15 /bin/bash
```

you can skip the pull step, if the image doesn't exist it will be pulled anyway.  the pull guarantees you get the freshest one.

Comment: Sure, this works. But what if the image contains business data or other IP? This answer just encourages people to do something potentially unsafe and is not even necessary. The other two answers are much better options, especially in a business environment.

Comment: oh well. i tried to delete the answer and i can't because it is the accepted answer. i agree that is isn't the best answer.  i don't think it is horrible either. even doing a save/load has its security implications.  in any event, if @eugene will move the accepted answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: Sure but in most businesses sending data to a third-party service is a no-go, while the local filesystem is trusted. About your answer, you can still edit it and leave a note that this might be unsafe for the reasons I mentioned.

Answer (score 37):

If your different linux host is on the same network you can transfer saved image using FTP or local HTTP server or share to transfer the file locally. 
Usage of Save :

```
docker save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

Example : `sudo docker save -o ubuntu.tar ubuntu:precise ubuntu:unicorn`

where `-o` saves to a file, instead of STDOUT. 
Transfer this tar file to the other linux host.Load this tar file in the new host using: `docker load [OPTIONS]`

Example: `sudo docker load --input fedora.tar`

where `--input` reads from a tar archive file, instead of STDIN.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. You don't need a network connection between the machines and you can even store the file in any way you want.

Answer (score 5):

Docker hub is one option to move your file.
But from a production point of view it is better to run a registry(place to store images) in the machine where you want to send your image .

For example you want to send your image from system1 to system2.
Let your image name be my_image.

Now open a registry in system1 by running

```
docker run -p <system1-ip>:5000:5000 -d registry
```

push your image into that registry :

You need to rename the image with :5000/my_image by using tag option

```
docker tag my_image <system1-ip>:5000/my_image
```

Now push into registry by using push command

```
docker push <system1-ip>:5000/my_image
```

Now go to system2 and pull your image from registry .

```
  docker pull <system1-ip>:5000/my_image
```

This is the most secured way of transferring images.
Reference link [creating a private repository](http://java.dzone.com/articles/create-your-own-private-docker)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know creating your own registry was this simple. +1