# how to save docker image for later installation?

Tags: docker

There is a docker image I need to load on station which is not connected to the internet
(i.e I can't use `docker pull` command)

So on the station which is connected to the internet, I want to download the docker image and copy it to the other station (which is not connected to the internet) and run it.

How can I do it this?

Comment: Why not copy across the resulting *image*?

Comment: how can we do it ?

Comment: Either check out their git repo for the file or see if the file content is shown on docker hub. Not sure where you pull the image from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to package a docker image in a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334706/how-to-package-a-docker-image-in-a-single-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `docker save` command to save one or more images to a tar archive.

More info here-> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

On the system with internet

```
$ docker pull <image>
$ docker save <image> > <image>.tar
```

Then copy this `.tar` file to a usb, and use `docker load` to unpack it on the other station.